# How to debug android SDK classes?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, sdk

I want to check why sometimes my invalidate() not call onDraw.
1 step: I set a breakpoint on invalidate().

2 step: I click "Step Into" button (also tried "Force Step Into"). But debugger goes not inside invalidate(). It goes inside getElevation() instead. Why?

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDtMf.png)

Also, I tried to set a breakpoint inside invalidate() method of View class on line invalidate(true);. But it also remains unreachable. It says that "No executable code ...".

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvsWq.png)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it partially.
Device version must be the same as SDK sources version, compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, targetSdkVersion.

In my case SDK sources API 24.

build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 24
    ...
}
```

Tracing now works (with these parameters only on API 24 device) but breakpoints still don't work (same No executable code error).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download the **Sources for Android SDK** for your targetSdkVersion inside build.gradle and see if you can debug inside the methods then.

But note that the newest Android API 25 does not have the sources available yet.

Comment: I have done this operation before I start debugging.