# Debug Android zygote process

Tags: android, debugging, gdb

I'm studying Android system startup and am very interested in the zygote process. Is there anyway to debug zygote with gdb or other tools? I've tried to do it with virtual machine like VMware or qemu but failed, all google results are about kernel debugging. By debug I mean I could set breakpoint, step into, check register value, etc... with gdb just like the normal process debugging with gdb.

Comment: Do you want to debug the source code of zygoteto to understand(verify) the workflow of system startup?  Seems to need to download and make the source code and should know the workflow. (read some analysis articles, I think)

Comment: I've read zygote souce code and knew exactly the workflow, I just want to debug these daemon processes, in some cases it will help a lot.

Comment: What's the mean of `debug`, I read your description, I understand that you want to add sth. debug log in source code and check it with `adb logcat command`, right? If I am correct, as I know, you should download the source code, then add your debug log in the code, compile it and flash it into an emulator or device. If you only want to check the log (like this: E/Zygote  (26122): isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted)  How about the command `adb logcat`?

Comment: debug means I could set breakpoint, step into, check the register value etc with gdb just like the normal process debug with gdb..  using Android logger system, you have to modify the source code and compile it again and again, it's a wast of time in this way.

Comment: How about the Android Studio?   dev2qa.com/how-to-debug-android-sdk-source-code-in-android-studio/        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946305/how-to-debug-android-sdk-classes

Comment: I think it can't work, it only  debug running apps or processes, native process startup or Debugging app startup as said in https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/gdb

Answer (score 0):

I post this question and after several tries. I found one way to debug daemon processes as long as it started after adbd:

1. Stop zygote
2. Gdbserver attach init process
3. Restart zygote
4. Debug its child process

Comment: What if the Android process you are trying to debug is protecting itself against `ptrace` / is attaching its own debugger to itself so that no other debuggers can be attached?

Also, I don't see `gdbserver` anymore for `ndk-v25`